# Binding a Tekton Workspace directory to a VolumeMount

Tags: kubernetes, ready-api, tekton, tekton-pipelines

We have a Tekton pipeline from which we want to run our ReadyAPI test suites. We're using the official image from SmartBear (https://hub.docker.com/r/smartbear/ready-api-soapui-testrunner).

The image requires that you bind the `/project` folder in the container to the host directory where the ReadyAPI test project is located. In our case, our test project is located in the Tekton `Workspace` directory `common-workspace/application-foo/tests/application-foo-readyapi-project.xml`.

When running the container image locally (with `docker run`), I would just add an argument `-v="common-workspace/application-foo/tests/":/project`. I can't figure out how to do this mapping in a Tekton `Task`. Here is the entire `Task` definition:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: run-readyapi-tests
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: source
  steps:
    - name: run-test-suite
      image: image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/cicd/ready-api-soapui-testrunner:3.20.0
      volumeMounts:
        - name: readyapi-project
          mountPath: /project
      env:
        - name: LICENSE_SERVER
          value: "a.b.c.d:1234"
        - name: COMMAND_LINE
          value: "/project/application-foo-readyapi-project.xml"
  volumes:
    - name: readyapi-project
      [some binding mechanism here]
```

Looking at the official docs on volume binding
with `hostPath` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath), I was hoping I could do something like this, but this doesn't work for some reason:

```
  volumes:
    - name: readyapi-project
      hostPath:
        path: common-workspace/application-foo/tests
```

So how can I bind `volumeMounts` to actual directories on the host? Any clues?

*Update:*
When looking at the pods in OpenShift, this `Task` has a `CreateContainerError` status. In the Events view, this is the error message that is displayed: "Error: failed to mkdir common-workspace/application-foo/tests: mkdir common-workspace: operation not permitted"

I don't understand why it tries to create the common-workspace folder, since it already exists. I have verified that the entire path exists when using the `emptyDir` volume type, and then running `ls /workspace/source/common-workspace/application-foo/tests`. This prints out the test project's XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: run-readyapi-tests
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: source
      mountPath: /project
  steps:
    - name: run-test-suite
      image: image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/cicd/ready-api-soapui-testrunner:3.20.0
      env:
        - name: LICENSE_SERVER
          value: "a.b.c.d:1234"
        - name: COMMAND_LINE
          value: "/project/application-foo-readyapi-project.xml"
```

You can set arbitrary mountPaths for your Tasks workspaces. The default being to mount them into `/workspace/${name}`.

You don't need the `volumeMounts` from your initial post. You could use it, if you had some `volumes` defined some place, but since you're only using `workspaces` here: they would be automatically mounted in all steps container from your Task.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear from the original post, but I have defined a `volumes` section at the bottom. It's just separated by text. I have edited my post to make this clearer.

Thank you for your answer - but I will still need to bind `/projects` to where the test suite is actually located in the `Workspace` (/workspace/source/common-workspace/application-foo/tests). From the official docs on the image, it also seems as if the volume binding is a requirement to run the container.